# Is it possible to incorporate ndpi with iptables nfqueue?

Tags: iptables

I would like to know if it is possible to mark traffic with ndpi (ntop.org) classification engine with iptables nfqueue?

Is there any example code out there?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can take the following link as an
example [nfq_ndpi_firewall](https://github.com/robingoth/nfq_ndpi_firewall) Then you can use nfq_set_verdict2() function from libnetfilter_queue library to set mark on the packet , after identifying the protocol.